# PLSQL procedure to add numbers by fetching records from table

Tags: oracle, plsql

PL/SQL procedure to add the values in each row of a table and DBMS output all the results row wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  l_what varchar2(10);         --> fail or pass
begin
  for cur_r in (select col1, 
                       col2, 
                       col3,   --> to be compared with
                       col1 + col2 result 
               from your_table)
  loop
    l_what := case when cur_r.col1 + cur_r.col2 = cur_r.col3 then 'pass'
                   else 'fail'
              end;

    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.col1 ||' + '|| cur_r.col2 ||' = ' || cur_r.result ||' -> '|| l_what);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

**[EDIT: a function that sums values in a table]**

Based on Scott's schema, this function will sum SAL and COMM values:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal, comm from emp where comm is not null;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN            1600        300
      7521 WARD             1250        500
      7654 MARTIN           1250       1400
      7844 TURNER           1500          0

SQL> create or replace function f_sum (par_empno in number)
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select sal + comm
  7      into retval
  8      from emp
  9      where empno = par_empno;
 10    return retval;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select empno, ename, sal, comm, f_sum(empno) result
  2  from emp
  3  where empno = 7499;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM     RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7499 ALLEN            1600        300       1900

SQL>
```

Comment: this worked as per my expectation..

Comment: I have a third column - expected result. i want to compare the result derived from the above procedure with the expected result column value(row to row) and get o/p as Fail/Pass. Is there any package to rum unit test case. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've modified code I wrote and added the "comparison" stuff. Have a look, please.

Comment: yes this is helpful. do you have any idea about plugins available to connect to jenkins from DB where I can compare the results and get a fail/pass report kinds

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know Jenkins at all.

Comment: That's okay.. Thanks a lot for the help. till here it worked fine for me

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, How can I write a function instead of the first procedure, to perform addition of 2 numbers by fetching values from tables

Comment: I edited my message; have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to have a loop implemented, Like it has to return values retrieved by adding each row. Also how do I call that function in a package to retrieve the result set